# Как правильно "раСспицовка" или "раЗспицовка"?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, приставка

Сборка велосипедного колеса (вернее, только одна операция) называется **спицовка** колеса.
Операция, обратная спицовке, соответственно должна называться как-то так: *ра**с**спицовка* или *ра**з**спицовка*. Подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: Суммарно действия по работе со спицами — переспицовка колеса.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: расспицовка.

Можно посмотреть: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rndIlQSbjs

Ремонт и обслуживание мотоцикла/ расспицовка переднего колеса 21"

Приставка РАС выбрана по правилу (перед глухой С в корне).